# Non-affinely parametrized geodesics

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, affine-geometry, geodesic, connections

Consider a non-affinely parameterised geodesic, i.e., a geodesic whose tangent vector field obeys $\nabla_X X = fX$ for some function $f$. Prove that one may reparameterise the geodesic so the tangent field $\tilde X$ obeys $\nabla_{\tilde X} \tilde X = 0$ (affine parameterised).

Attempt: Let $t \mapsto \gamma(t)$ be such a geodesic with tangent vector field $X = \frac{d}{dt} g(\gamma(t))$ where $g$ is some smooth function defined over the manifold. Now reparamatrise, so that $t \rightarrow t(z) \mapsto \gamma(t(z))$ Then let $\tilde X$ be the tangent vector of this newly paramatrised curve.  So $$\tilde X = \frac{dt}{dz} \frac{d}{dt} g(\gamma(t)) = \frac{dt}{dz} X \equiv  X/h$$

Then $$\nabla_X X = fX \Rightarrow \nabla_{h \tilde X} (h \tilde X) = h^2 \nabla_{\tilde X} \tilde X + h \tilde X(h) \tilde X = fh \tilde X.$$  So provided $\tilde X(h) = f$ I am done.  But I don't see why this is true or if there is a fault previously.  Many thanks!

Comment: Perhaps it is so simple that I can just define $f$ to be that quantity?